# Select and submit form with python requests library

Tags: python, python-requests, mechanize

I am trying to scrape data from [this](http://forestsclearance.nic.in/Wildnew_Online_Status_New.aspx) website. To access the tables, I need to click the "Search" button. I was able to successfully do this using mechanize:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(url + 'Wildnew_Online_Status_New.aspx')
br.select_form(name='aspnetForm')
page = br.submit(id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Button1')
```

"page" gives me the resulting webpage with the table, as needed. However, I'd like to iterate through the links to subsequent pages at the bottom, and this triggers javascript. I've heard mechanize does not support this, so I need a new strategy.

I believe I can get to subsequent pages using a post request from the requests library. However, I am not able to click "search" on the main page to get to the initial table. In other words, I want to replicate the above code using requests. I tried

```
s = requests.Session()
form_data = {'name': 'aspnetForm', 'id': 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Button1'}
r = s.post('http://forestsclearance.nic.in/Wildnew_Online_Status_New.aspx', data=form_data)
```

Not sure why, but this returns the main page again (without clicking Search). Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)

Comment: I've used scrapy in the past to scrape a similar webpage, but it ended up being easier to use the requests library. In this case, I'll be able to scrape all the the pages with requests, the only thing holding me back is getting past the "Search" button on the main page.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot some parameters in ths post request:
https://www.pastiebin.com/5bc6562304e3c
[image]
check the Post request with google dev tools